# Why does scrum use the average instead of the median when calculating velocity?

Tags: scrum, velocity

Could somebody please explain this to me. It seems to me that the number of story points actually delivered at the 50th percentile would be more valuable than a theoretical number that is far more likely to get affected by outliers, especially in the early days of an organization adopting scrum.

Comment: Someone promote this man! He's thinking forward, saving resources, and I'm pretty sure he's been synergizing all morning. It's probably because more bosses understand what an average is than a median.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a statistically significant method to calculate velocity, you might try using the *average* and *standard deviation*. This way, you will be able to predict with whichever degree of certainty you are required what your velocity is.

If you wish, you can limit the data to the last few sprints, if you notice a change in the trend, and can explain it as valid.

This goes towards the Agile values of communication and courage (for the stakeholders to accept the uncertainty of the prediction).

e.g.

Team: Based on the last 5 sprints, we are 90% certain that we will be able to deliver *at least* 30 SP in the next sprint.

Comment: You provide an interesting example. Does this mean it is up to the team and not the scrum master to estimate their current velocity?

Comment: Yes, and No.  
**Yes** - it is definitely, _always_ up to the team, to provide estimates. The Scrum Master is in charge of the _process_, and _no_ authority over the team (he's a master of the Scrum, not the team).  
**No**, because the velocity is measured and calculated, not estimated (at least not after the first sprint).

Comment: Thanks. We've adopted something very similar. We now track two velocities - the overall average and the average over the last 3 sprints. We use these two numbers as guides on what we should commit to. This works because we're currently in the accelerating phase as far as velocity goes. This means that the 3 sprint window usually serves as our upper bound, because when you're just starting scrum, the hardest part usually is not over committing.

Answer (score 3):

Actually nobody says that you can't use median. Scrum just shows way to drive the proces but you can bend it (improve it) to your needs and understanding.

Comment: +1: Furthermore, they're both perfectly awful ways to predict the future.  One is not actually more statistically significant than the other.   There are so many degrees of freedom that the difference between this is unmeasurable.

Comment: @Ladislav: Isn't "bending" scrum to their needs what causes teams to fail initially when they're trying to adopt it? Isn't that also one of the duties of the scrum master? To be the guardian of the process? However, I can understand bending scrum once the team is humming nicely.

Comment: @S.Lott: What would be a better way?

Comment: @carleeto: Sure, that was meant by the part - to your needs and **understanding**. You should always start with recommended approach and once you have enough experience and see the possibility of improvement you can try it.

Comment: @carleeto: There is no "better" way.  They're all inaccurate because of the huge number of degrees of freedom.  Software development is encoding knowledge in a programming language.  The scope and technical obstacles cannot be known (by definition).  The only way to know the scope and all the technical obstacles is to have a complete implementation before planning a complete implementation.  You cannot predict the future and you cannot predict the future of software development efforts.

Comment: In my understanding Scrum is a framework that defines the frame and you do the work *g*... nay, just kidding. The framework says, you shall calculate the velocity as an average of the previously done stories. It's not that precisely in mathematical terms, so it doesn't forbid to use the median or sth similar.

Answer (score 1):

scrum doens't use average or median, it's a particular team that will choose one over the other depending upon the sophistication they want..

I will suggest if outliers are the problem then choose something like average of last 7 to 9 iterations... so once you are in lets say 15th iteration you won't be having any effect of early 'bad' iterations... .

Answer (score 0):

I've found measures such as average sprint velocity (or median in your case) to be a very poor way to determine what the next sprint velocity may be.  The main problem is that the formula is driving the decision making and this allows a team and SM to substitute that for real thinking.

The best way to compute next-sprint velocity that I've found (using Scrum for almost 5 years) is the following:

In the first sprint or two, it's just an educated guess.  We make a guess then drop back from that a bit to ensure we don't overshoot.

If the team has picked up, say 5 extra pts in the prior sprint, increase the velocity by no more than 5 points.  If the team didn't pick up any new points, keep the velocity where it is unless they struggled.  If they struggled, back off a bit, say, 10%.

If the sprint failed, regroup and figure out whether it was because the team picked too much work.  If so, work out what stories were actually done 100% - this total of points is your new velocity for the next sprint.